# Trouble with created object added to a list

Tags: java, swing

i've going through a little program and got an error that i'm not able to find solution for.

My objective was to add to a list ( used ArrayList ) a created object ( BlockObject extending from JPanel ) create by triggering a click, and then be able to read the list to print it on the screen, but at the time of reading such list i get ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

I've been debugging and found the reason of the trouble, and it's that i don't know why, each object that i create and add to it retrieve the latest type ( explained ahead ) and not the one with which it was created.

The code that runs along the list is

```
    public void ListBlock(){

    BlockObject auxb;
    Point auxp;

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        auxb = list.get( i );

        if( auxb.getType() != 0 ){

            auxp = list.get( i ).limitBounds( 0, list.get( i - 1 ).getHeight() );
            auxb.setBounds( ( int ) auxp.getX(), ( int ) auxp.getY(), GlobalDataStorage.StatementWidth, GlobalDataStorage.StatementHeight );
        }
        add( auxb );
    }

}
```

The trouble said it's because it gets always in the if() condition, so even the first element takes the previous one ( being the cause of the OutOfBounds ), but there is already an element inside at each moment which would be type 0 to jump it, and the rest enter in it:

```
   list = new ArrayList<BlockObject>();
    startingBlock = new BlockObject( 0 );
```

The type there is 0, but it changes as explained ahead, that's what shouldn't happen and don't know why it does.

The following elements are added:

```
    public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent evt ) {

        point = new Point( evt.getX(), evt.getY() );;

        if( ( findComponentAt( point ) instanceof BlockObject ) && ( StatementPanel.getType() != 0 ) ){

            list.add( new BlockObject( StatementPanel.getType() ) );

            ListBlock();
            revalidate();
            repaint();

        }

    }
```

The type at the BlockObject creation it's saved in a variable, and it's supposed to not change, so each creation i thought that would be saved in the list with a value, but it keeps changing all the previous objects created when at StatementPanel a new leaf it's selected ( StatementPanel it's implemented following a JTree, each leaf a different type ).
Though maybe that was the static method to get the type, but didn't work adding a different one.

Maybe the problem is obvious and i can't see it.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger, then you can investigate errors such as this yourself, and in far less time than it took you to write this question. http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: Sounds like a static variable problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer after seeing your comment i've checked the variables and that was the problem, kept one as static and left it as if was normal. Didn't imagine that would bring me such trouble. Thank you for the help and all who replied to the post for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

i assume you have this problem:

```
Example e = new Example();
e.ChangeValue("e");
List<Example> examples = new List<Example>();
examples.add(e);
e.ChangeValue("e2");
examples.add(e);
```

the problem with this is that if you add e to the list it just creates a reference to the object and both added to the list are pointing to the same reference (so changing one would change the other too), solution to this would be Create a new Object a new Example and copy it's values to it, that way you would not have the reference problem and could change only one at a time